# How can I download a secure file from S3 via a url with no expiration window?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a **Django** application which needs to access files in my **AWS S3** bucket. We are currently doing this successfully using [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages), where the file can be downloaded via the `url` method (code [here](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/47f373ef6f18e467844aa67b06cb4736d9cad958/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L485-L495)).

The crux of that method is the `generate_url()` method that boto supplies:

```
return self.connection.generate_url(self.querystring_expire,
        method='GET', bucket=self.bucket.name, key=self._encode_name(name),
        headers=headers,
        query_auth=self.querystring_auth, force_http=not self.secure_urls,
        response_headers=response_headers)
```

However, this method returns a url with a signature and expiry that *opens* the file to the world for **60 minutes** (or a specified amount of time; I think 60 minutes is the default).

For example: running `generate_url()` for a file located in `s3://my-bucket/myfile.txt` will return the the url:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/myfile.txt?
  X-Amz-Date=20150710T161246Z
  &X-Amz-Expires=300
  &X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
  &X-Amz-Signature=<SIGNATURE>
  &X-Amz-Credential=<CREDENTIAL>
  &X-Amz-SignedHeaders=Host
  &x-amz-security-token=<SECURITY_TOKEN>
```

Which, when clicked downloads the file as expected. The issue is that after the file has been "opened" by accessing this url, then the "unsigned" url (`https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/myfile.txt`) is open for 60 minutes as well - without requiring the signature and other query string parameters.

*Is there a way to require the signature every single time the file is accessed?* It seems like there should be. Even if I change the expiry to 1 second, the url-without-signature is open to the world for that 1 second.

I am working with sensitive information, and need to be complient with certain security standards, etc, so having my file open to the world for even a second is a no-no.

**Does anyone know how to generate an AWS S3 url for a file that requires a signature on every download?**

I have also been exploring using proxy servers, but these seem like they do the same thing, only visibly hide the url from the end user. Example [here](https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files) and [here](http://distinctplace.com/infrastructure/2013/09/18/use-nginx-to-proxy-files-from-remote-location-using-x-accel-redirect/). But the file would still be accessible (without signature) to the world (if someone - or a bot - was able to guess the S3 url. Not likely, I know, but still not allowed).

Ideally, I'd like to find a Python/Django package that handles accessing a file in a 100% secure way, that can be served via url.

Comment: *The issue is that after the file has been "opened" by accessing this url, then the "unsigned" url (https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/myfile.txt) is open for 60 minutes as well - without requiring the signature and other query string parameters.* ... What you describe is *not* what S3 does. Are you getting this information from documentation, test results, or...?

Comment: Test results using the django-storages package.

Comment: You have made an error in your test observations, or the file in S3 was not stored securely to begin with.  S3 does not "open" a file for insecure access when it is accessed with a signed URL. The behavior you describe simply is not possible. Please test again, or provide actual observable examples of URLs exhibiting the behavior.  If the object's acl is public-read, it's going to be globally visible without the signature.

Comment: Found out that `dango-storages` is uploading the file as public. So this issue in in that package. Couldn't have figured that out without your help though, so much appreciated!